# TeamCity MSTest Not Reporting All Tests: Failed to read testDuration

Tags: mstest, teamcity, data-driven-tests, vs-unit-testing-framework

I am pretty new to Team City and Jet Brains products in general.

I'm using MSTest for running some tests (VS Unit Tests).  I was able to configure Team City to run the tests using a metadata file and a testlist.

However, Team City is not reporting all of the tests.  It says "9 Passed" instead of "9 Passed/2 Failed"

The two tests that cannot be read are Data Driven tests.  Does this pose a problem?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

From the build log:

```
9/11 test(s) Passed, 2 Failed
Summary
-------
Test Run Failed.
Passed 9
Failed 2
----------
Total 11
Results file: ..\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\tmp4E9E.tmp.teamcity.trx
Test Settings: Local
Run has the following issue(s):
EXEC Test Run deployment issue: The assembly or module 'XmlDiffPatch' directly or indirectly referenced by the test container '..\build\output\alpha\ds9\erpservicestest\bin\alpha\erpservicestest.dll' was not found.
The command ""..\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe" /runconfig:..\Build\Output\Alpha\DS9\Local.testsettings /testmetadata:..\Build\Output\Alpha\DS9\DS9.vsmdi /resultsfile:..\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\tmp4E9E.tmp.teamcity.trx /testlist:ERPServices_IntegrationTests /test:Manufacturing_ManufacturingPlanning_CreateEngineeringMaster /testlist:ERPServices_IsAlive" exited with code 1.
##teamcity[importData id='mstest' file='..\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\tmp4E9E.tmp.teamcity.trx']
Importing data from '..\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\tmp4E9E.tmp.teamcity.trx' with 'mstest' processor
MSTest
[MSTest] Found 11 test definitions.
[MSTest] ERPServicesTest.InventoryServiceUnitTests.InventoryService_GetPart_IsAliveTest
[ERPServicesTest.InventoryServiceUnitTests.InventoryService_GetPart_IsAliveTest] [Test Output] Endpoint = ../ERPServices/InventoryService.svc
[ERPServicesTest.InventoryServiceUnitTests.InventoryService_GetPart_IsAliveTest] Done Building Project "..\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\478837a28017f91d\Build\Build_DS9.proj.teamcity.patch.tcprojx" (DeployTests;TeamCity_Generated_MSTestTests target(s)).
[MSTest] ERPServicesTest.PurchaseServiceUnitTests.PurchaseService_CreateSupplierReturn_IsAliveTest
[ERPServicesTest.PurchaseServiceUnitTests.PurchaseService_CreateSupplierReturn_IsAliveTest] [Test Output] Endpoint = ../ERPServices/PurchasingService.svc
[MSTest] ERPServicesTest.AuthorizationServiceUnitTests.AuthorizationService_GetUserByADUsername_IsAliveTest
[ERPServicesTest.AuthorizationServiceUnitTests.AuthorizationService_GetUserByADUsername_IsAliveTest] [Test Output] Endpoint = ../ERPServices/AuthorizationService.svc
[MSTest] ERPServicesTest.ManufacturingServiceUnitTests.ManufacturingService_GetWorkOrder_IsAliveTest
[ERPServicesTest.ManufacturingServiceUnitTests.ManufacturingService_GetWorkOrder_IsAliveTest] [Test Output] Endpoint = ../ERPServices/ManufacturingService.svc
[MSTest] ERPServicesTest.QualityServiceUnitTests.QualityService_GetAllStatuses_IsAliveTest
[ERPServicesTest.QualityServiceUnitTests.QualityService_GetAllStatuses_IsAliveTest] [Test Output] Endpoint = ../ERPServices/QualityService.svc
[MSTest] ERPServicesTest.GeneralServiceUnitTests.GetCountry
[ERPServicesTest.GeneralServiceUnitTests.GetCountry] [Test Output] Endpoint = ../ERPServices/GeneralService.svc
[MSTest] ERPServicesTest.PublicServiceUnitTests.PublicService_GetPMStatuses_IsAliveTest
[ERPServicesTest.PublicServiceUnitTests.PublicService_GetPMStatuses_IsAliveTest] [Test Output] Endpoint = ../ERPServices/PublicService.svc
[MSTest] ERPServicesTest.PurchaseServiceUnitTests.PurchaseService_AddReceiverNoteByReceiver_IsAliveTest
[ERPServicesTest.PurchaseServiceUnitTests.PurchaseService_AddReceiverNoteByReceiver_IsAliveTest] [Test Output] Endpoint = ../ERPServices/PurchasingService.svc
[MSTest] ERPServicesTest.LogServiceUnitTests.LogService_GetLogItem_IsAliveTest
[ERPServicesTest.LogServiceUnitTests.LogService_GetLogItem_IsAliveTest] [Test Output] Endpoint = ../ERPServices/LogService.svc
[MSTest] Test 'ERPServicesTest.ManufacturingServicesIntegrationTests.ManufacturingService_AddWorkOrderNote_Neg_IntTest': Failed to read testDuration
[MSTest] Test 'ERPServicesTest.ManufacturingServicesIntegrationTests.ManufacturingService_AddWorkOrderNote_Pos_IntTest': Failed to read testDuration
[MSTest] 9 test(s) were reported
Build succeeded.
```

Comment: Any resolution to this? Was the issue the missing/not found assembly?

Comment: I did not resolve this and am currently far removed from the issue. Are you running the latest versions of MSTest & TeamCity? Would be surprised if this was still an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add the XmlDiffPatch assembly to the Deployment list in the .testsettings file you are referencing.

> The assembly or module 'XmlDiffPatch' directly or indirectly referenced by the test container '..\build\output\alpha\ds9\erpservicestest\bin\alpha\erpservicestest.dll' was not found.